# how to get domain name in mongoose server c++

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server

I am using http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ server inside my c++ application. I am looking a way to find domain name in c++ code. 
Is there any api in mongoose to get current domain name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve it by calling -

```
const char *value = mg_get_header(connection, "Host");
```